How to create the illusion of a moving train
i want to render a scene where a character is sitting on a moving train. The scene takes place at night, there are only shots inside the train, one with the camera moving forward toward the character. You just have to be able to see the outside like in a tunnel, the lights who cross the windows, to give the sensation of movement.
But here's my problem, i don't know how to fake movement, i tried to put some lights who are moving in front of the windows but that doesn't satisfy me.
I found the effect that i want on a video. But i have no idea how to recreate this.
Thanks for your help 
the link is the reference that i want to recreate

You're gonna need to be more precise on what you want to achieve. You can put 2 planes with videos on it, create a full CG environment, create just some abstract colored lights, ... How does your current iteration "not satisfy you" ? You didn't show it to us. Also, motion blur is mandatory in your case I would say.

you could add some shake on the camera and the carriage to sell the effect, but the main part of the illusion of motion will still be ¨some lights who are moving in front of the windows¨
